# Splitting a sentence into words then swapping the first and last letters of each word

Tags: java

I need to enter a sentence and get the computer to split the sentence into words and then swap the first and last letter of each word. I need to use arrays for this.  So far the code I have used works ok to enter a word and swap the first and last letter but now I need to modify it to enter a sentence.  Any advise on how I can do this?  I am not very familiar with arrays.

```
public class FirstNLast {

    private String word;
    private String newWord;
    private StringBuilder strBuff;
    private int len;
    private char firstLetter;
    private char lastLetter;

    public FirstNLast() {
        word = "";
        newWord = "";
        strBuff = new StringBuilder();
        len = 0;
        firstLetter = ' ';
        lastLetter = ' ';
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public void compute() {
        len = word.length();
        firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
        lastLetter = word.charAt(len - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i = i + 1) {
            if (word.charAt(i) == firstLetter) {
                strBuff.append(lastLetter);
            } else if (word.charAt(i) == lastLetter) {
                strBuff.append(firstLetter);
            } else {
                strBuff.append(word.charAt(i));
            }
            newWord = strBuff.toString();
        }
    }

    public String getNewWord() {
        return newWord;
    }
}
```

Comment: look up the `split()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [String.split(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method to split the sentence by spaces. The method will give you an array of Strings (in your case words). Then iterate through the array and do what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public String mutateSentence(String input) {
  String[] words = input.split(" ");
  String output = "";    
  for (int i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
    String modifiedWord = yourMethodOfFlippingLetters(words[i]);
    output += modifiedWord;
  }
  output.trim(); // removes the trailing space added
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to use your class with a full sentence :

```
FisrtNlast f = new FirstNLast()
String words[] = sentence.split(' ');
String words[] = sentence.split(' ');

String out = null;
for( word in words){
  f.setWord(word);
  f.compute();
  out +=' ' + f.getNewWord();
}

sysout(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would first need to split up the sentence into its separate word components. The Split method basically cuts the sentence into pieces at each of the spaces.

```
String sentence = "The quick brown fox";
String[] words = sentence.Split(" ");
```

So here, words would equal:

```
{ "The", "quick", "brown", "fox" }
```

Now that each word is separated and placed into an array, you can iterate through the array and swap the first and last letters.

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    char[] wordCharArray = word[i].toCharArray();
    char firstLetter = wordCharArray[0]; // Holds the first so we can replace it.
    wordCharArray[0] = wordCharArray[wordCharArray.length - 1]; // Sets the first letter as the last.
    wordCharArray[wordCharArray.length - 1] = firstLetter; // Sets the last letter as the original first.
    words[i] = new String(wordCharArray); // Just converts the char array back into a String.
}

sentence = new String(words);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split() like this

```
String word,output = "";
String something = "This is a sentence with some words and spaces";
String[] parts = something.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
    word = flipLetters(parts[i]); /* swap the letters in the word*/
    output += word + " ";
}
```