# Trying to get a sentence to be split into words then swap the first and last letter of each word

Tags: java

Does anyone know why it's not working out?

Here is the code for the main class:

```
public class FirstNLast {
    private String word[];
    private String sentence = "";
    private String newWord;
    private StringBuilder strBuff;
    private int len;
    private char firstLetter;
    private char lastLetter;

    public FirstNLast(){
        word = sentence.split(" ");
        newWord = "";
        strBuff = new StringBuilder();
        len = 0;
        firstLetter = ' ';
        lastLetter = ' ';
    }

    public void setSentence(String sentence) {
        this.sentence = sentence;
    }

    public void compute(){
        len = word.length;
        firstLetter=word[0].charAt(0);
        lastLetter=word[len-1].charAt(len-1);

        for (int i=0; i < word.length; i = i + 1) {
            if (word[i].charAt(i)==firstLetter) {
                strBuff.append(lastLetter);
            }
            else if (word[i].charAt(i)==lastLetter) {
                strBuff.append(firstLetter);
            }
            else {           
                strBuff.append(word[i].charAt(i));
            }
            newWord = strBuff.toString();
        }
    }

    public String getSentence(){
        return sentence;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my App class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FirstNLastApp {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String sentence = "";
        String[] word = sentence.split(" ");

        String newWord;
        StringBuilder strBuff;
        int len=0;
        char firstLetter;
        char lastLetter;

        FirstNLast fnl = new FirstNLast();

        sentence = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a sentence");

        fnl.setSentence(sentence);

        fnl.compute();

        sentence=fnl.getSentence();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The new word is " + sentence);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is not working out? Where is the problem you are encountering? What do you expect to happen and what is happening right now?

Comment: This question looks to be a continuation from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571660/splitting-a-sentence-into-words-then-swapping-the-first-and-last-letters-of-each)? But whats the problem this time?

Comment: DoubleDouble its compiling fine but its not running.

Comment: Your question and comment are like saying this:  *"Doctor.  I am feeling sick.  What is the cure?"*

Comment: @user109649 your code is little bit confusing, but it is a good problem for practice :)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't watch your code, but I will answer your question in the title:

```
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    String newSentence = "";

    for(String word : words){
        char[] letters = word.trim().toCharArray();
        char firstChar = letters[0];
        letters[0] = letters[letters.length - 1];
        letters[letters.length - 1] = firstChar;
        newSentence += new String(letters) + " ";
    }

    return newSentence;
```

To understand why your code is not working, you should follow **Stephen C**'s tips :)

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use your IDE's built-in debugger.  Set some breakpoints, and use single stepping and the debugger's variable viewer to watch what is happening.

I can't give you detailed instructions on how to do this because it depends on your IDE.  But there will no doubt be help / tutorial information on how to do this.  After that, it is a matter of learning how to do it for yourself.  (And the sooner you learn to do it for yourself, the better!)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for the Instantiable class.  It works for swapping the first and last letters of a word.  But then my problem was I needed to input a sentence and apply this to each word in the sentence so I left this class alone and created a new class called FirstNLast where I worked out how to split a sentence.

```
public class FirstNLastWord {

    private String word;
    private String newWord;
    private StringBuffer strBuff;
    private int len;
    private char firstLetter;
    private char lastLetter;

    public FirstNLastWord() {

        word = "";
        newWord = "";
        len = 0;
        firstLetter = ' ';
        lastLetter = ' ';
    }
    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public void compute() {

        strBuff = new StringBuffer();
        len = word.length();
        firstLetter=word.charAt(0);
        lastLetter=word.charAt(len-1);

        for(int i=0; i < word.length(); i = i + 1) {

            if(word.charAt(i)==firstLetter) {
                strBuff.append(lastLetter);
            }
            else if(word.charAt(i)==lastLetter) {
                strBuff.append(firstLetter);
            }

            else {
                strBuff.append(word.charAt(i));

            }
            newWord = strBuff.toString();
        }
    }
    public String getNewWord() {
        return newWord;
    }
}
```

Here is the FirstNLast class to figure out how to split the sentence.

```
public class FirstNLast{

    private String word[];
    private String sentence, newWord;
    private String newSentence;
    private StringBuffer strBuff;
          private int len;
    private char firstLetter;
    private char lastLetter;
    private FirstNLastWord fnl;

    public FirstNLast(){
        sentence = "";
        newSentence = "";
        strBuff = new StringBuffer();
        len = 0;
        firstLetter = ' ';
        lastLetter = ' ';
        fnl=new FirstNLastWord();
    }
    public void setSentence(String sentence){
        this.sentence = sentence;
    }
    public void compute(){

        word = sentence.split(" ");
        len = word.length;


        for(int i=0; i < word.length; i = i + 1){
            fnl.setWord(word[i]);
            fnl.compute();
            newSentence= newSentence+" "+fnl.getNewWord();
        }

     }

     public String getNewSentence(){
         return newSentence;
     }
}
```

And finally my app class to enter the sentence.  It works perfectly fine.  So in all 3 classes.  One class to change the first and last letters of a word. One class to change all the words in a sentence in the same way and a third to enter and display the sentence.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FirstNLastApp{

    public static void main(String[]args){


        String sentence="";
        String word[]=sentence.split(" ");
        String newSentence="";
        StringBuffer strBuff;
        int len=0;
        char firstLetter;
        char lastLetter;

        FirstNLast fnl = new FirstNLast();


        sentence = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a sentence");


        fnl.setSentence(sentence);


        fnl.compute();

        newSentence=fnl.getNewSentence();


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The new sentence is " + newSentence);

    }
}
```